# Does TFS download all working folders in build definition?

Tags: tfs, build, tfsbuild

In my build definition under "Working folders", I have `$/MyProject/Main/Source` mapped to `$(SourceDir)`.

Does that make it download all files in `$/MyProject/Main/Source` to `$(SourceDir)`? Or does it only download what is included within the solution that I'm building if it exists within `$/MyProject/Main/Source`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will download all files under that folder.

If you want to limit what it downloads you can add other paths to the workspace mapping and mark them as "cloak" which will indicate to TFS not to download the cloaked folders.