# TFS 2013 Build Agent Getting all, instead of just one solution

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, build-agent

I am seeing all branches and such being pulled to the build agent build folder even though I specified the solution I want to build. Any ideas or blogs I can look at that might specify how I can limit the GET scope...?

I presume I need to be more specific in my Build Agent folder...

[image: Picture of Build Agent Working folders]

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431351/does-tfs-download-all-working-folders-in-build-definition but esentially Yes, narrow down your source paths, or use Cloak as described in other Answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TFS Build will download everything in your workspace mapping (it doesn't use the solutions to build to determine what to download).

You can specify one or many folders in the workspace mapping, you can also specify "cloaked" folders to tell it specifically not to download certain folders.

Comment: I will look into the cloak feature.  Thanks for the input.